# css for dynamic rows not working

Tags: php, css, styles

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>truck page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        tr {
            padding: 4px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
        $db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "db1");
        function getdata($form_element_name) {
            $var = strip_tags($_GET[$form_element_name]);
            return $var;
        }
    ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend> add a new truck </legend>
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="GET"> 
            <label>truck number <input type="text" name="truck_number" /></label>
            <label>owner name <input type="text" name="truck_owner_name" /></label>
            <label>owner phone <input type="text" name="truck_owner_ph" maxlength="10" /></label>
            <input type="submit" name="truck_add"  value="add" />
            <input type="reset" />              
        </form>
        <?php if(isset($_GET['truck_add'])) {
            $truck_number = getdata('truck_number');
            $truck_owner_name = getdata('truck_owner_name');
            $truck_owner_ph = getdata('truck_owner_ph');
            $sql_truck_add = "INSERT INTO truck (truck_number, truck_owner_name, truck_owner_ph) 
                                            VALUES ('$truck_number', '$truck_owner_name', '$truck_owner_ph' )"; 
            $result_truck_add = $db->query($sql_truck_add);     
            header("Location: http://localhost/bkp/truckpage.php");             
        } ?>
    </fieldset>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>truck number</th>
            <th>owner name</th>
            <th>phone</th>
            <th>operation</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $sql_truck_retrieve = "SELECT * from truck";
        $result_truck_retrieve= $db->query($sql_truck_retrieve);
        while($row=$result_truck_retrieve->fetch_assoc()) { 
            $truck_num_current = $row['truck_number']; ?>
            <tr id="<?php echo "{$truck_num_current}"; ?>">
                <td><?php echo "{$row['truck_number']}"; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo "{$row['truck_owner_name']}"; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo "{$row['truck_owner_ph']}"; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="GET">
                        <input type="hidden" name="truck_numcur" value="<?php echo "{$row['truck_number']}"; ?>" />
                        <input type="submit" name="truck_update" value="update" />
                        <input type="submit" name="truck_delete" value="delete" />
                    </form>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php // action to be taken if either update or delete is selected
                    if(isset($_GET['truck_update'])) { 
                        $truck_numcur = $_GET['truck_numcur'];
                        if($truck_numcur == $truck_num_current) { ?>
                            <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="GET">  
                                <input type="hidden" name="truck_update_num" value="<?php echo "{$truck_numcur}"; ?>" />
                                <input type="text" name="truck_num_update" placeholder="truck number" />
                                <input type="text" name="owner_name_update" placeholder="owner name" />
                                <input type="text" name="owner_phone_update" placeholder="owner phone" />
                                <input type="submit" value="save" name="truck_update_yes" />
                                <input type="submit" value="cancel" name="truck_update_no" />
                            </form>
                        <?php }
                    }
                    else {
                        if(isset($_GET['truck_delete'])) {
                            $truck_numcur = $_GET['truck_numcur'];
                            if($truck_numcur == $truck_num_current) {
                            ?>
                                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="GET">
                                    <span>confirm? </span>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="truck_del_num" value="<?php echo "{$truck_numcur}"; ?>" />
                                    <input type="submit" name="truck_delete_yes" value="yes" />
                                    <input type="submit" name="truck_delete_no" value="no" />
                                </form>
                            <?php }
                        }
                    }
                    //
                    // action to be taken after delete confirmation
                    if(isset($_GET['truck_delete_yes']))  {
                        $truck_del_num = $_GET['truck_del_num'];
                        $sql_truck_del = "DELETE from truck WHERE truck_number = '{$truck_del_num}'";
                        $result_truck_del = $db->query($sql_truck_del);
                        header("Location: http://localhost/bkp/truckpage.php");
                    }
                    else {
                        if(isset($_GET['truck_delete_no'])) {
                            header("Location: http://localhost/bkp/truckpage.php");
                            //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
                            //header("Location: http://localhost/bkp/truckpage.php/#$truck_num_current");
                            //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        }
                    }
                    //
                    // action to be taken after update confirmation
                    if(isset($_GET['truck_update_yes'])) {
                        $truck_update_num = $_GET['truck_update_num'];
                        $truck_num_update = getdata('truck_num_update');
                        $owner_name_update = getdata('owner_name_update'); 
                        $owner_phone_update = getdata('owner_phone_update');
                        $sql_truck_update = "UPDATE truck SET truck_number = '$truck_num_update', truck_owner_name = '$owner_name_update', truck_owner_ph = '$owner_phone_update' WHERE truck_number = '{$truck_update_num}' ";
                        $result_truck_update = $db->query($sql_truck_update);
                        header("Location: http://localhost/bkp/truckpage.php");
                    }
                    else {
                        if(isset($_GET['truck_update_no'])) {
                            header("Location: http://localhost/bkp/truckpage.php");
                        }
                    }
                    //
                    ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>  
    </table>
</body>
```

I am trying to extract values from a db table and add them as table rows. The rows are being shown correctly but when I tried to add css styles for the table rows it did not work. I tried to give a border and padding.I am new to web development and cannot understand why the css part is not working.Can anyone please tell how to make the css part work in this php code?

Comment: make sure that these lines exist before your first line
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>

Comment: those are written. Everything except the css for tr is working properly

Comment: ok I am editing the post and uploading the entire php code

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in that you cannot very effectively style `tr` elements. You will need to target the parent `table` or the child `td` elements to get the affect you're looking for.

Check out this JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/v6zNt/

**CSS:**

```
table {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

/* notice how these styles does not apply anywhere */
tr {
    border: 1px solid green;
    padding: 4px;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td>Three</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can style tables, it's just that they have their own set of rules that you need to be mindful of. Here's a great introduction: http://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/